# Preference checkbox stays true even when unchecked

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a preference activity in which I have a PreferenceCheckBox.

My preference activity:

```
package com.tjs.balr;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity{

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource( R.xml.preferences); 
    }   
}
```

My checkbox:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Audio">
        <CheckBoxPreference
            android:id="@+id/checkSound"
            android:summary="Turn sounds on or off"
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:title="Sounds"
            android:key="soundPref" 
        />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

In my main activity I try to get the value of my checkbox using:

```
private void showUserSettings() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    musicPlaying = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("checkSound", true);

    if(musicPlaying){
        Toast.makeText(this, "music is turned on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "music is turned off ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

A LOT of people here on stackoverflow describe `musicPlaying = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("checkSound", true);` as the way to get the value of the checkbox, but in my case it stays true. Mainly because I say the default value of `checkSound` is true. Am I forgetting something in order to change the value of my PreferenceCheckBox? To my understanding of an PreferenceActivity all data is saved automatically, is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `getBoolean(key, defaultValue)` , you need to pass the **Key** not the id.

You get always `true` because he dont find the `CheckBox` with *checkSound* as key so it return the default value (`true` in your case).

To fix that, just change

`musicPlaying = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("checkSound", true);`

to

`musicPlaying = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("soundPref", true);`

Comment: Wow, never even looked at my Key or ID. I'm sorry for my sloppyness :(